# How Convert SQL Query to Lambda Expression with Inner Join

Tags: c#, sql-server, lambda

```
 SELECT computer.*,
       computerdetail.manufacture,
       computerdetail.model,
       computerdetail.noofshares,
       computerdetail.phymem,
       computerdetail.processor,
       computerdetail.numloproc,
       computerdetail.numphproc
FROM   computer
       INNER JOIN computerdetail   ON computer.id = computerdetail.computerid
```

Comment: where is lambda expression? give some sample data with proper explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide any details what you want. So assuming you just want to convert your query to the `lambada expression` using `Join` the conversion can be as below,

```
var result = computer.Join(computerDetail,comp=>comp.id,compdet=>compdet.computerid,
         (comp,compdet)=> new 
                         {
                           Manufacturer = compdet.manufacture,
                           Model = compdet.model,
                           ... //more properties to select
                         }).ToList();
```

this will return you the list of the `anonymous` objects.

Comment: i want to select all the data in these two tables into one grid view. and i would like to use lambada expression query. im using entity framework in visual studio 2012 and using c#.